# Overriding Doctrine_Record (sfDoctrineRecord) instance methods in Doctrine PHP Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, extending, getter-setter

My background is in Propel, so I was hoping it would be a simple thing to override a magical getter in a Doctrine_Record (sfDoctrineRecord), but I'm getting either a Segfault or the override method is simply ignored in favor of the one in the superclass.

https://gist.github.com/697008eaf4d7b606286a

```
class FaqCategory extends BaseFaqCategory
{

  public function __toString()
  {
    return $this->getCategory();
  }

  // doesn't work
  // override getDisplayName to fall back to category name if getDisplayName doesn't exist
  public function getDisplayName() {

    // also tried parent::getDisplayName() but got segfault(!)
    if(isset($this->display_name)) {
      $display_name = $this->display_name;
    } else {
      $display_name = $this->category;
    }

    return $display_name;

  }

}
```

What is the proper Doctrine way to extend/override methods on an instance of Doctrine_Record (via sfDoctrineRecord extends Doctrine_Record)? This has to be doable...or should I be looking at the Template documentation?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try _get and _set methods.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure about what do you wanted to do **exactly**, but here are some hints:

1. Doctrine (with `ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE` attribute enabled, which **is** enabled by symfony) allows you to override certain component columns' getters just by defining `getColumnName` methods in model class. That's why your `getDisplayName` method can fall infinite loop which usually causes segfault.
2. To access/modify column value directly (bypassing custom (get|set)ters) you have to use `_get('column_name')` and `_set('column_name')` methods defined by `Doctrine_Record` class.
3. All the `$obj->getSomething()`, `$obj->something` and `$obj['something']` calls are actually magical. They are "redirected" to `$obj->get('something')` which is only **real** way to access model data.

Comment: Thanks for the info on ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE; now I see where in  Doctrine_Record that is checked before sending back the value of the field. -br

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
class FaqCategory extends BaseFaqCategory
{

  public function __toString()
  {
    return $this->getCategory();
  }

  public function getDisplayName() {

    if($this->_get("display_name") != "") {
      $display_name = $this->_get("display_name");
    } else {
      $display_name = $this->getCategory();
    }

    return $display_name;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Configure Doctrine:

```
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE, true);
```

then:

```
public function getAnything()
{
    return $this->_get('anything');
}

public function setAnything()
{
    return $this->_set('anything', $value);
}
```

Comment: Will this work if say Anything = 'test_var' ? I'm trying to get getter methods to work with field names that have underscores but somehow that's not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Shivaas Try with `getTestVar` for `test_var`