# Doctrine Override Getters and Setters for Relation fields

Tags: doctrine, overriding, foreign-key-relationship, getter-setter

Does anyone know how to override Doctrine_Record getters and setters for Relation fields. For example if I have a class **Note**, **Note** has many **Users**, now can I *override*, for example, this operation **Note->Users[] = $user1** ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Never tried it myself but you should be able to do this with `_get` and `_set`. There is also a post here on SO that asks almost the same thing:

[Overriding Doctrine_Record (sfDoctrineRecord) instance methods in Doctrine PHP Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587115/overriding-doctrine-record-sfdoctrinerecord-instance-methods-in-doctrine-php-sy)

Comment: I have already tried doing it in this way, but all I get is just an error. I am able to set basic fields, but not the ones which have relation with other tables.